# Why useDispatch re-renders parent components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm using useDispatch hook (from Redux) in `onSelect` callback in the Tree component (from Ant library):

```
export const MyComponent = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onSelect = (selectedNode) => {
            const selectedItem = selectedNode[0];
            dispatch(fetchSelectedItems(selectedItem));
    };

    return 
        <Tree
            onSelect={onSelect}
        >
            <TreeNode .. />
            <TreeNode .. />
            <TreeNode .. />
        </Tree
}


export const fetchSelectedItems = (selected: string) =>
    (dispatch) =>
        axios({
            url: `/api/items?id=${selected}`,
            method: 'GET',
        }).then(response => {
            dispatch(fetchSelectedItemsSuccess(response.data))
        }).catch((error: any) => {throw(error)});
```

Why does `useDispatch` re-render parent components? Is there any way to prevent from this? I tried `useCallback` like it's in Redux documentation but [this solution](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) is to prevent child components from re-rendering, not parents.

Comment: Hi @kriz Welcome to stack overflow. Can you provide code for `fetchSelectedItems` and parents? (because the parent uses data retrieved via `fetchSelectedItems`, then the parent would rerender).  A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be great.

Comment: This happens even if I do some 'dummy' dispatch like `dispatch({ type: 'SOME_ACTION_NAME' })`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my assumption in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515755/why-usedispatch-re-renders-parent-components/60525672#comment107058274_60515755) was correct.

So I will show you the workaround.
You can extract the part that uses `clickValue` in the container to another component, say `ClickValue`.

Doing so will isolate the update to `ClickValue` component only.

My fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/soanswer60515755-9cc7u

```js
function ClickValue() {
  const clickValue = useSelector(state => state.value);
  console.log(clickValue);
  return clickValue;
}

export default function Container() {
  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <h3>Container</h3>
      <ParentComponent />
      <ClickValue />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check out the profile result below.

[image: profile result]

Comment: Thanks for that. It helps when you need to render something. In my case I needed values to be passed so in the end I rewrote my selectors using reselect library and now they're momoized which solves my problem.

Comment: You're welcome & thanks for sharing the answer. Could you add your solution as a reply and mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that on every render you are redeclaring the onSelect function.  Functions are reference types.  Passing that redeclared function with its new reference on ever render will cause a rerender.  Perhaps you should look into using context.

Comment: Does that cause the parent to re-render?

Comment: Any reference change to any prop anywhere will cause a rerender

Comment: But not a from the child to the parent.

Comment: If you declare a function within a component any state change that causes that parent to enter a render cycle will make a new function.  This is exactly why you cannot do a debounce within a function and you are required to use the useCallback hook.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with re-rendering components was caused by `useSelector` used in parent components where I directly refer to `state`. Most probably because of new result of this selector..

Solution:
I rewrote this selectors with [reselect library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect) to make them memoized (it was suggested in one of comments here but I don't know why its've been removed). I did exactly what is in redux documentation about [memoized selectors](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors).